# Is this statement True or False

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I have a statement

$S$ : "It is not the case that 5 is even or 7 is prime."

Let $A$ = "5 is even" and $B$ = "7 is prime".

The *not* word in the statement $S$ is applicable to both $A$ and $B$, right?

The statement $S$ means ${(A \cup B)}^{\complement}$.

Since  ${(A \cup B)}$ is `true`, the statement $S$ is `false` right.

Can you verify this answer?

Comment: 5 is even or 7 is prime is true. Hence, it's negation is false.

Comment: That would have been better written as "It is not the case that:  '5 is even or 7 is prime'".  As it stands, it is ambiguous what the "not" refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `True` that $7$ is prime.
Thus it is `True` that $5$ is even or $7$ is prime.
And thus its negation is `False`.